# Disable notifications or sound on apps with DND permissions enabled

Tags: notifications, do-not-disturb

I have some apps installed that demand that I grant them permissions to send me notifications even if DND is enabled. If I don't grant them these permissions, they will not operate. I need these apps in particular to perform my job, so I cannot choose to use an alternative app. Aside from cutting the wires to the phone's speaker, how else could I silence these needy apps?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.